# Under what circumstances can a vtable pointer be null (or 0x1)?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, crash, vtable

I am currently debugging a crashlog. The crash occurs because the vtable pointer of a (c++-) object is 0x1, while the rest of the object seems to be ok as far as I can tell from the crashlog.

The program crashes when it tries to call a virtual method.

My question: Under what circumstances can a vtable pointer become null? Does operator delete set the vtable pointer to null?

This occurs on OS X using gcc 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493).

Comment: Can you clarify if the function pointer in the vtable is 0 or if it's the this pointer that is null? Or is it a pointer in the object that is pointing to the current vtable?

Comment: The vtable pointer is 1. The crash occurs while trying to execute

`call   *0x1c(%eax)` (in at&t syntax)

and the value of eax is 1 (not zero as I stated incorrectly).

Comment: Run it in gdb, set a watch-point at the address, see what's writing it.

Comment: Either you have a bug somwhere else that is trampling memory. Or your object is not fully formed (You can __not__ call virtual methods during construction or destruction). There is no definitive answer to your question as the standard has nothing to say about v-tables and each compiler is completely different.

Comment: Nikolai: "I am currently debugging a crashlog."

Martin: Of course there is a bug somewhere in the code, and it is none of the trivial ones. It has nothing to do with the c++ standard. This is about finding out what bug can cause this specific behavior using gcc 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could be a memory trample - something writing over that `vtable` by mistake. There is a nearly infinite amount of ways to "achieve" this in C++. A buffer overflow, for example.

Answer (score 8):

Any kind of **undefined behaviour** you have may lead to this situation. For example:

- Errors in pointer arithmetic or other that make your program write into invalid memory.
- Uninitialized variables, invalid casts...
- Treating an array polymorphically might cause this as a secondary effect.
- Trying to use an object after delete.

See also the questions [What’s the worst example of undefined behaviour actually possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908872/whats-the-worst-example-of-undefined-behaviour-actually-possible) and [What are all the common undefined behaviour that a C++ programmer should know about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367633/what-are-all-the-common-undefined-behaviour-that-c-programmer-should-know-about).

Your best bet is to use a bounds and memory checker, as an aid to heavy debugging.

Answer (score 7):

A very common case: trying to call a pure virtual method from the constructor...

**Constructors**

```
struct Interface
{
  Interface();
  virtual void logInit() const = 0;
};

struct Concrete: Interface()
{
  virtual void logInit() const { std::cout << "Concrete" << std::endl; }
};
```

Now, suppose the following implementation of `Interface()`

```
Interface::Interface() {}
```

Then everything is fine:

```
Concrete myConcrete;
myConcrete.pure();    // outputs "Concrete"
```

It's such a pain to call pure after the constructor, it would be better to factorize the code right ?

```
Interface::Interface() { this->logInit(); } // DON'T DO THAT, REALLY ;)
```

Then we can do it in one line!!

```
Concrete myConcrete;  // CRASHES VIOLENTLY
```

Why ?

Because the object is built bottom up. Let's look at it.

Instructions to build a `Concrete` class (roughly)

1. Allocate enough memory (of course), and enough memory for the _vtable too (1 function pointer per virtual function, usually in the order they are declared, starting from the leftmost base)
2. Call `Concrete` constructor (the code you don't see)

   a> Call `Interface` constructor, which initialize the _vtable with its pointers

   b> Call `Interface` constructor's body (you wrote that)

   c> Override the pointers in the _vtable for those methods Concrete override

   d> Call `Concrete` constructor's body (you wrote that)

So what's the problem ? Well, look at `b>` and `c>` order ;)

When you call a `virtual` method from within a constructor, it doesn't do what you're hoping for. It does go to the _vtable to lookup the pointer, but the `_vtable` is not fully initialized yet. So, for all that matters, the effect of:

```
D() { this->call(); }
```

is in fact:

```
D() { this->D::call(); }
```

When calling a virtual method from within a Constructor, you don't the full dynamic type of the object being built, you have the static type of the current Constructor invoked.

In my `Interface` / `Concrete` example, it means `Interface` type, and the method is virtual pure, so the _vtable does not hold a real pointer (0x0 or 0x01 for example, if your compiler is friendly enough to setup debug values to help you there).

**Destructors**

Coincidently, let's examine the Destructor case ;)

```
struct Interface { ~Interface(); virtual void logClose() const = 0; }
Interface::~Interface() { this->logClose(); }

struct Concrete { ~Concrete(); virtual void logClose() const; char* m_data; }

Concrete::~Concrete() { delete[] m_data; } // It's all about being clean
void Concrete::logClose()
{
  std::cout << "Concrete refering to " << m_data << std::endl;
}
```

So what happens at destruction ? Well the _vtable works nicely, and the real runtime type is invoked... what it means here however is undefined behavior, because who knows what happened to `m_data` after it's been deleted and before `Interface` destructor was invoked ? I don't ;)

**Conclusion**

**Never ever call virtual methods from within constructors or destructors.**

If it's not that, you're left with a memory corruption, tough luck ;)

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed answer. In my case, this is not the case, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

My first guess would be that some code is `memset()`'ing a class object.

Answer (score 1):

This is totaly implementation dependant. However it would be quite safe to assume that after delete some other operation may set the memory space to null.

Other possibilities include overwrite of the memory by some loose pointer -- actually in my case it's almost always this...

That said, you should never try to use an object after delete.

Comment: delete certainly may do so, but I'm not aware of any implementation where it does

Comment: @Neil: implementations are not my field. I changed the answer to something "more true"...