# Why does object have NULL vtable pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, clang++, libtooling

I'm using libTooling built from source (git tag: `llvmorg-16.0.6`) for searching diff of AST level.

When using my built product, Segmentation fault occured.

Through inspection by gdb, I found that this is from libTooling,
and the segmentation fault occured at calling `A->getSourceRange()`([source](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/7cbf1a2591520c2491aa35339f227775f4d3adf6/clang/lib/Tooling/ASTDiff/ASTDiff.cpp#L439))

```
if (auto *A = dyn_cast<AccessSpecDecl>(D)) {
    CharSourceRange Range(A->getSourceRange(), false);
    return std::string(
        Lexer::getSourceText(Range, AST.getSourceManager(), AST.getLangOpts()));
}
```

Also, gdb shows that `A`'s vtable pointer(`_vptr.Decl`) is `0x0`.

```
(gdb) p *A
$1 = {<clang::Decl> = {_vptr.Decl = 0x0, NextInContextAndBits = {Value = 0}, 
    DeclCtx = {<llvm::pointer_union_detail::PointerUnionMembers<llvm::PointerUnion<clang::DeclContext*, clang::Decl::MultipleDC*>, llvm::PointerIntPair<void*, 1, int, llvm::pointer_union_detail::PointerUnionUIntTraits<clang::DeclContext*, clang::Decl::MultipleDC*>, llvm::PointerIntPairInfo<void*, 1, llvm::pointer_union_detail::PointerUnionUIntTraits<clang::DeclContext*, clang::Decl::MultipleDC*> > >, 0, clang::DeclContext*, clang::Decl::MultipleDC*>> = {<llvm::pointer_union_detail::PointerUnionMembers<llvm::PointerUnion<clang::DeclContext*, clang::Decl::MultipleDC*>, llvm::PointerIntPair<void*, 1, int, llvm::pointer_union_detail::PointerUnionUIntTraits<clang::DeclContext*, clang::Decl::MultipleDC*>, llvm::PointerIntPairInfo<void*, 1, llvm::pointer_union_detail::PointerUnionUIntTraits<clang::DeclContext*, clang::Decl::MultipleDC*> > >, 1, clang::Decl::MultipleDC*>> = {<llvm::pointer_union_detail::PointerUnionMembers<llvm::PointerUnion<clang::DeclContext*, clang::Decl::MultipleDC*>, llvm::PointerIntPair<void*, 1, int, llvm::pointer_union_detail::PointerUnionUIntTraits<clang::DeclContext*, clang::Decl::MultipleDC*>, llvm::PointerIntPairInfo<void*, 1, llvm::pointer_union_detail::PointerUnionUIntTraits<clang::DeclContext*, clang::Decl::MultipleDC*> > >, 2>> = {Val = {Value = 0}}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, Loc = {ID = 0}, DeclKind = 0, InvalidDecl = 0, HasAttrs = 0, Implicit = 0, Used = 0, Referenced = 0, 
    TopLevelDeclInObjCContainer = 0, static StatisticsEnabled = false, Access = 0, FromASTFile = 0, IdentifierNamespace = 0, CacheValidAndLinkage = 0}, ColonLoc = {ID = 0}}
```

I switch compiler from `/usr/bin/c++` to `clang++`, but problems are no solved. I also compile with libTooling and clang-15 from `apt install`, but it also raise segmentation fault that seems occurred at other position (raised at `clang::diff::SyntaxTree::Impl::getDeclValue` for clang built from source, and at `clang::diff::SyntaxTree::Impl::getStmtValue` for clang-15 from apt)

Because two compiler's binaries (`c++` and `clang++`) cause same segmentation fault, I suspect that I did something wrong, but I do not know what.

Please teach me why there is NULL vtable pointer, and how to solve this.

The repository for reproduction is [here](https://github.com/Soya-Onishi/libToolingSegmentationFault/tree/main).

Comment: Does `A` have any virtual functions?

Comment: What's `dyn_cast`? And if that's an upcast, returned pointer may be null if original object is not compatible. Vtable can be null while neither base nor derived types have vtable - n0 virtuals.

Comment: There is a bug somewhere in the executed code that results in undefined behavior. Only hands-on debugging can possibly determine the reason why, so, unfortunately, it is unlikely that anyone on Stackoverflow will be able to tell you anything...

Comment: Probably because `dyn_cast` returns a nullptr.

Comment: @NathanPierson I think `getSourceRange()` is virtual function. [link](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/7cbf1a2591520c2491aa35339f227775f4d3adf6/clang/include/clang/AST/DeclBase.h#L420)

Comment: @PepijnKramer
Probably `dyn_cast` did not fail because `A` has instance, but its instance has NULL vtable pointer.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie You mean downcast? As far as I know, `D`, downcast source variable, is `Decl` type and `AccessSpecDecl` is subclass of `Decl`.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Another question, what is n0 virtuals? I googled but I cannot find what it is.

Comment: It's "no virtuals" but in SwiftKey accent :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic question, of how the vtable pointer can be `NULL`, is already
asked and answered here:

- [Under what circumstances can a vtable pointer be null (or 0x1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072256/under-what-circumstances-can-a-vtable-pointer-be-null-or-0x1)

However, the hypotheses suggested in the answers to that question are
not a perfect match for the symptoms here, and the libtooling angle has
some novel aspects, so I'll refrain from calling it a duplicate, even
though it's quite close.

### It's all zeroes

From the `gdb` output, we can see that *everything* is zero, not just
the vtable pointer.  That suggests that the pointer is pointing
somewhere it shouldn't, at memory which happens to contain all zeroes.
It's also possible something overwrote the entire AST memory with
zeroes.

As a demonstration, if we have a class with a vtable:

```
class C {
public:
  int m_x, m_y;
  virtual ~C() {}
};
```

and create a pointer pointing at zeroes:

```
  unsigned char arr[80];
  std::memset(arr, 0, sizeof(arr));
  C *p = reinterpret_cast<C*>(&arr[0]);
```

then `gdb` will report a zero vtable:

```
(gdb) print *p
$1 = {_vptr.C = 0x0, m_x = 0, m_y = 0}
```

Somehow you've done something to create a similar situation.

### libtooling connection

The pointer in question ostensibly points to a
[libtooling](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html)
[`Decl`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Decl.html) AST
node.  But everything is zero, including the `DeclKind`.

The reason the crash happens inside this conditional is
that a `DeclKind` of zero happens to be the value used by
[AccessSpecDecl](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1AccessSpecDecl.html)
to identify itself to
[`dyn_cast`](https://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#the-isa-cast-and-dyn-cast-templates).

The reason it crashes on the call `A->getSourceRange()` is that
`getSourceRange` is a `virtual` function, but the vtable pointer is
`NULL`, so dereferencing that pointer causes a crash.

### How to debug this?

In a case like this, where the crash site itself does not offer much
information, you want to start cutting out as much from your program as
you can, while preserving the fact that it fails in this way.
Presumably you started from some libtooling hello-world tutorial example
that does not exhibit this behavior.  Remove the pieces of your program,
one by one, until you have nothing but the original tutorial code.  At
some point you'll remove a piece that causes the problem to go away; put
that back and keep removing other pieces.

If, by doing that, you figure out the problem, then great, you're done.
Otherwise you'll have a minimal reproducer that could be the basis of a
new question.  (But don't just link to a github repo.  The question
should be self-contained.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and advice. From your advice, I figure out where my code is wrong.